# How to check if a check_box in simple_form has been checked

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Here's the HTML that it produces

```
f.check_box :tos
```

produces

```
<input name="user[tos]" type="hidden" value="0">

<input id="user_tos" name="user[tos]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

What would I need to do in a controller to check if it's been checked?

Comment: Do you mean what would you need to do to test that it has been checked?   Your controller wouldn't check if it has been checked would it?   Or do you want the controller to do something if checked but something else if not?

Comment: If you could please add more context to your question to clarify what you are looking for.  Your controller won't have access to the information in the input(e.g. whether or not it was checked) until the information is submitted. At that point the value of the form element will be part of the user object that is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to find out if it is checked upon *submission*, then you could get it's value via `params[:user][:tos]`. All submitted data from a form is stored in the params hash, and its location is equivalent to the name attribute of the input. So for instance:

```
if params[:user][:tos] == "1"
    # Do whatever is here if checked
else
    # Do whatever is here if unchecked
end
```

If you need to react to its state of being checked on a web page, this cannot be done by the controller, and must use JavaScript. Something like:

```
if (document.getElementById('user_tos').checked == 1){
    // Do whatever is here if checked
} else {
    // Do whatever is here if unchecked
}
```

**Addendum**

When receiving a parameter via your controller, don't use that value to create a new object (i.e. `Thing.create( thing_value: params[:user][:tos] )`). If this is y our goal, you should look into "strong parameters," and how Rails implements them.

**Addendum 2**

Thanks to ruby's duck typing (dynamic typing) and the nature of the params Hash, url encoding, etc. Integers sent via params, in this case `params[:user][:tos]`, will get mutated to **String**. So you'll need to check for "1" (the string form) not 1 (the int form).

Answer (score 0):

In th controller, all parameters are delivered in the hash `params`.
Your `params` will have a key `user` with the hash of all user input fields.

The hidden field, that simple_form insterts before the checkbox ensures that `params[:user][:tos]` is set (with value 0) even when the checkbox is not set.

So you can check

```
if params[:user][:tos]>0
  # your stuff
end
```